# QT and OpenCascade out of memory

Tags: c++, windows, qt, opencascade

I am starting to code with OpenCascade in QT, finding this interesting basic project:
https://github.com/eryar/occQt/

I have compiled the program with:

> QT       += core gui opengl

and when I execute it, I get the following error:

> TKOpenGl | Type: Performance | ID: 0 | Severity: Low | Message:   VBO
>   creation for Primitive Array has failed for 169 vertices. Out of
>   memory?

I have also posted the issue in the project site, but I am not sure about the activity in that place.
That is why I am asking you if you had any idea to workaround.

My testbed:

- Intel i7 with 8GB of memory
- Windows 10
- OpenCascade 6.9.1 vc12-64
- QT 5.5.1

Answer (score 1):

i didn't try to compile the program but after a quick look it may be a **GPU driver** problem ,for some reason glGenBuffer didn't genetate the buffer object
this is how i deduced that >>
in occt6.9.1 , file OpenGl_PrimitiveArray.cxx ,the function :

```
Standard_Boolean OpenGl_PrimitiveArray::initNormalVbo (const Handle(OpenGl_Context)& theCtx) const
```

there is :

```
  if (!myVboAttribs->init (theCtx, 0, myAttribs->NbElements, myAttribs->Data(), GL_NONE, myAttribs->Stride))
  {
    TCollection_ExtendedString aMsg;
    aMsg += "VBO creation for Primitive Array has failed for ";
    aMsg += myAttribs->NbElements;
    aMsg += " vertices. Out of memory?";
    theCtx->PushMessage (GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_APPLICATION_ARB, GL_DEBUG_TYPE_PERFORMANCE_ARB, 0, GL_DEBUG_SEVERITY_LOW_ARB, aMsg);

    clearMemoryGL (theCtx);
    return Standard_False;
  }
```

which means that , in file OpenGl_VertexBuffer.cxx the function :

```
bool OpenGl_VertexBuffer::init (const Handle(OpenGl_Context)& theGlCtx,
                                const GLuint   theComponentsNb,
                                const GLsizei  theElemsNb,
                                const void*    theData,
                                const GLenum   theDataType,
                                const GLsizei  theStride)
{
  if (!Create (theGlCtx))
  {
    return false;
  }

  Bind (theGlCtx);
  myDataType     = theDataType;
  myComponentsNb = theComponentsNb;
  myElemsNb      = theElemsNb;
  theGlCtx->core15fwd->glBufferData (GetTarget(), GLsizeiptr(myElemsNb) * theStride, theData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
  bool isDone = (glGetError() == GL_NO_ERROR); // GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY
  Unbind (theGlCtx);
  return isDone;
}
```

returned false,

because

```
bool OpenGl_VertexBuffer::Create (const Handle(OpenGl_Context)& theGlCtx)
{
  if (myBufferId == NO_BUFFER)
  {
    theGlCtx->core15fwd->glGenBuffers (1, &myBufferId);
  }
  return myBufferId != NO_BUFFER;
}
```

returned false , which means that myBufferId is still equal to NO_BUFFER as set in the constructor of OpenGl_VertexBuffer
which means that

```
theGlCtx->core15fwd->glGenBuffers (1, &myBufferId);
```

didn't change any thing . the comment in OpenGl_Context.hxx line:583 says

```
  OpenGl_GlCore15Fwd*  core15fwd;  //!< OpenGL 1.5 without deprecated entry points
```

the OpenGl_GlCore15Fwd::glGenBuffers function is just calling the OpenGL function as in file OpenGl_GlFunctions.hxx

```
  inline void glGenBuffers (GLsizei n, GLuint *buffers)
  {
    ::glGenBuffers (n, buffers);
  }
```

it may be wrong deduction but I didn't dig deeper